# In Laravel 5.6, how do I create relative links?

Tags: url, laravel-5, href

I'm new to Laravel (using 5.6) and can't get my links to work.

My directory structure is: **resources/views/pages/samples**

In the **samples** directory, I have 10 blade files I want to link to (named "sample1.blade.php", etc.). I have a "master" links page in the **pages** directory (one level up from **samples**).

I've tried the following but can't get any of them to work correctly...

```
<a href="/sample1">Sample 1</a>
<a href="/samples/sample1">Sample 1</a>
<a href="{{ url('/samples/sample1') }}">Sample 1</a>
<a href="http://site.test/views/pages/samples/sample1">Sample 1</a>
```

...and a few other variations.

I've also tried adding a **base** tag to the HTML header but that doesn't help.
Every time I click a link, it says "Sorry, the page you are looking for could not be found."

What am I missing?

Comment: you may be misunderstanding the resources folder. Are those paths added to your route file? take a look at [this](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/routing)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks **@happymacarts**, I didn't realize I had to add a path for every single page in my site.

After adding the paths, the links are working.

I will get into the practice of updating the paths every time I add a page.